# How to do a cross validation with NaiveBayesClassifier and movie_reviews corpus

Tags: python, nltk, cross-validation

I have been looking through stackoverflow and none of the answers work so thought I would ask this. I have been analysing the movie_reviews corpus in nltk, python. And I have no idea how to do a cross validation (k-fold). The answers on here are not working and I am wondering if it is because I am using python 3? How can I make a cross validation easily in python? Can I use cross_val_score, and if so how do I implement it?

I tried this:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold, cross_val_score
k_fold = KFold(len(y), n_folds=4, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
clf = classifier
print (cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=k_fold, n_jobs=1))
```

And also:

```
X = all_words_clean
kf = KFold(n_splits=2)
for train, test in kf.split(X):
    print("%s %s" % (train, test))
```

The first part of the code does not work at all and the second part just doesn´t seem like its cross validation (It works but the outcome is: [ 791910  791911  791912 ... 1583817 1583818 1583819] [     0      1      2 ... 791907 791908 791909]
[     0      1      2 ... 791907 791908 791909] [ 791910  791911  791912 ... 1583817 1583818 1583819])

I also want to get the accuracy after this.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The second code snippet just prints all the train/test indices, not any actual scores. You'll need to add a `clf.fit(X[train], y[train])` and a `clf.score(X[test], y[test])` to do the fitting and predicting, respectively.

Comment: And how do I do that? :)

Comment: Assuming you have your data (the `X` and `y` variables) set up correctly, then `cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=5)` should give you 5-fold cross-validated scores. The second approach you listed is pretty much trying to do this manually, instead of doing it through `cross_val_score`. What is the problem you have, specifically? Could you maybe give the error message you get, if it crashes?

Comment: Well I got nothing pretty much. The first one dont work at all because I dont have the X and Y set up. I am mostly wondering how to do that :)

Comment: This is pretty much what I have: test_set = feature_set[:500]
train_set = feature_set[500:]